# How I can attach a signed hash to a file?

Tags: hash, signature, reference-request

I am signing files through a web service. As I want to reduce the bandwidth consumption I am signing only hash, but I don't know how can I attach the signed hash to the file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

There are three distinct possibilities to store a signature:

- **detached signature** The signature is stored in a seperate file. The format can be freely chosen
- **enveloped signature** The signature is embedded within the original document. The format of the original document has to support this, of course (pdf and xml would be two possible examples)
- **enveloping signatures** You create a new file in an established signature format and use that as a container, embedding the original document. The most common format for that would be [Cryptographic Message Syntax/PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652), alternatively [XML signatures](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/) could be used for that.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. A little question: Where I can read about the enveloped signature?. Thanks

Comment: @PedroJavierBarrera The following might help... http://i.imgur.com/g22G0nQ.jpg

Comment: @PedroJavierBarrera: Do you have a particular format in mind?

Comment: Yes, I want to use PDF format. I will sign only the hash, and attach the hash signed to the document, throught someone function (I don´t know how do this), instead of signing the entire document (In theory).

Comment: Then you must use a PDF library which supports signatures. I know that [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) can create sigantures in Java and C#.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisifed, please accept the answer.